# Why is my create react app giving no output?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, crud, tailwind-css

I'm doing a tutorial for a basic CRUD app with React and Tailwind, this is my first time setting it up and I'm trying to display a navbar but when i run 'npm run start', the output is blank. Can anyone guide me as to why? Following this: https://www.unimedia.tech/2021/11/30/build-a-simple-crud-app-using-react-and-node/

[image]

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
export default function Navigate(){
   return (
       <nav class="flex items-center justify-between flex-wrap bg-green-500 p-6">
       <div class="flex items-center flex-shrink-0 text-white mr-6">
           <span class="font-semibold text-xl tracking-tight">REACT CRUD APP</span>
       </div>
       <Link to="/">
           <button class="inline-block text-sm px-4 py-2 leading-none border rounded text-white border-white hover:border-transparent hover:text-green-500 hover:bg-white mt-4 lg:mt-0">
               HOME
           </button>
       </Link>
       </nav>
   )
}
```

tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Navigate.js

```
import React from "react";
export default function Navigate(){
   return (
       <nav class="flex items-center justify-between flex-wrap bg-green-500 p-6">
           <div class="flex items-center flex-shrink-0 text-white mr-6">
               <span class="font-semibold text-xl tracking-tight">REACT CRUD APP</span>
           </div>          
           <div>
               <button class="inline-block text-sm px-4 py-2 leading-none border rounded text-white border-white hover:border-transparent hover:text-green-500 hover:bg-white mt-4 lg:mt-0">
                   CREATE
               </button>
           </div>
       </nav>
   )
}
```

index.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen',
    'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue',
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, 'Courier New',
    monospace;
}
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
reportWebVitals();
```

EDIT (New Output):
[image]

Comment: When you say "the output is blank," are you saying that the terminal doesn't show any kind of message after `npm run start` or that the page in your browser doesn't render anything?

Comment: @MarkG the webpack compiles successfully, the page just isn't rendering anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CHange your index.js file with this code. To work with Link you need to wrap your `<App/>` component with `<BrowserRouter>`. Also, it is best if you also add an output screenshot from the browser console as most of the time you will get detailed errors there.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: Success! I've got some output now, and no console errors, although it looks like the Tailwind classes aren't carrying over, any idea why this may be? I've uploaded a screenshot in the main post above.

Comment: Found the problem, I needed to run 'npm install react-scripts@latest' and its all working now, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

So I have not worked with react recently so I don't know if something might be changed in the new react-router-dom version, but I am sure you need to wrap your App component into `<Router></Router>` tags to render the `<Link>` tag.

Make changes in App.js as below and it will display your navbar.

```
import React from "react";
import { Link, BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Navigate() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <nav class="flex items-center justify-between flex-wrap bg-green-500 p-6">
                <div class="flex items-center flex-shrink-0 text-white mr-6">
                    <span class="font-semibold text-xl tracking-tight">
                        REACT CRUD APP
                    </span>
                </div>
                <Link to="/">
                    <button class="inline-block text-sm px-4 py-2 leading-none border rounded text-white border-white hover:border-transparent hover:text-green-500 hover:bg-white mt-4 lg:mt-0">
                        HOME
                    </button>
                </Link>
            </nav>
        </Router>
    );
```

Let me know if this solution works out.

Comment: This works (as does the solution above), I've got some output now, and no console errors, although it looks like the Tailwind classes aren't carrying over, any idea why this may be? I've uploaded a screenshot in the main post above.

Comment: Found the problem, I needed to run 'npm install react-scripts@latest' and its all working now, thanks for your help!

Comment: That's great. Btw I looked in the document you are following, so to understand what is mentioned in the article you need a basic knowledge of react and article is missing important points.

Comment: Yeah I think I'll have to do a bit more reading before continuing on with this one, thanks for your help!